# Unable to get my Ruby negative look ahead regex to work properly

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to search for a word in a string, but only if another word doesn't come before it.  I thought I could use this negative look-ahead, as shown below, but I'm still getting a match on the phrase "bad apple" when I don't want to complete the match if the word "bad" is before "apple".  It is NOT a given that there only be one space between the word "bad" and the word "apple."

```
2.4.0 :014 > word_regex = /(?!.*bad)(^|\s)#{Regexp.escape(word)}(\s|$)/i
 => /(?!.*bad)(^|\s)apple(\s|$)/i
2.4.0 :015 > "good apple".match(word_regex)
 => #<MatchData " apple" 1:" " 2:"">
2.4.0 :016 > "bad apple".match(word_regex)
 => #<MatchData " apple" 1:" " 2:"">
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: I think you want a _negative lookbehind_ e.g. `(?<!bad)`. See the [SO docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind#t=201705092018125034562&a=syntax)

Comment: Can there be arbitrary number of spaces between `bad` and `apple`? A lookbehind in Ruby is fixed-width, and [`/(^|(?<!\bbad)\s)#{Regexp.escape(word)}(?!\S)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/gU28vv/2) may not work properly in all cases. Actually, the fact that you are using whitespace as word boundary hints at the fact you can do without a regex here.

Comment: You might still use a lookahead, but the expression will look even uglier: [`(^\s*|\s(?!bad\s)\S+\s+)apple(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/gU28vv/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But, wait, negative lookaheads can be variable length!

```
R = /
    \b                 # match word break
    #{'apples'.reverse} # match 'elppa'
    \b                 # match word break
    (?!                # begin a negative lookahead
      \s+              # match one or more whitespaces
      #{'bad'.reverse} # match 'dab'
      \b               # match word break
    )                  # close negative lookaheaad
    /ix                # case-indifferent and free-spacing regex definition modes
#=> /
    \b                 # match word break
    elppa              # match 'selppa'
    \b                 # match word break
    (?!                # begin a negative lookahead
      \s+              # match one or more whitespaces
      dab              # match 'dab'
      \b               # match word break
    )                  # close negative lookaheaad
    /x

def avoid_bad_apples(str)
  str.reverse.match? R
end

avoid_bad_apples("good apples")           #=> true
avoid_bad_apples("Simbad apples")         #=> true
avoid_bad_apples("bad pears")             #=> false
avoid_bad_apples("bad apples")            #=> false
avoid_bad_apples("bad    apples")         #=> false
avoid_bad_apples("good applesauce")       #=> false
avoid_bad_apples("Very bad apples. BAD!") #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using negative lookbehind like this `(?<!bad\s)apple` will look for *apple* only when it's not preceded by `bad`. Note the space after `bad`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iq0X6J/1/)**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I am aware of that Sir. But since OP didn't mentioned multiple spaces I am assuming it's only one.

Comment: Wiktor is right, though.  I wanted to simplify my example, so I only put one space, but when I try multiple spaces -- /(?<!bad\s+)#{Regexp.escape(word)}(\s|$)/i , I get an "invalid pattern in look-behind" error.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, that's because fixed width lookbehind is not supported. Please update your post with multiple space requirements.

Comment: @engineersmnky: Of course one can pre-process the string. That is still not a universal solution (what if there can be punctuation or symbols between the two words?), but is an potential workaround for the current scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I tryied it and it's a look-behind like @sagarpandy82 said

```
word_regex = /(?<!bad)(^|\s)#{Regexp.escape("apple")}(\s|$)/i
a = "good apple".match(word_regex)
b = "bad apple".match(word_regex)
```